# (C++) How do I subtract a current subtraction to a previous one?

Tags: c++

My main problem is the ubalance, how do I make it so that it subtracts the total from principal and continues subtracting until I get 0? pls help;-; (Disclaimer: I am very much a beginner and this is for class, so I'm very much confused)

[Like in this photo, where unpaid balance subtracts from principal payment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F4Cbe.png)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

main()
{
    float lamount, interestr, lpayment, totali, principal, ubalance;
    int year, total;
    
    cout << "\n Loan Amount\t\t\t   : $ ";
    cin >> lamount;
    cout << " Loan Terms (in Years)\t\t   : "; 
    cin >> year;
    cout << " Annual Interest Rate (in decimal) : "; 
    cin >> interestr;
    
    cout << "\n\n Loan Amount: " << fixed << setprecision(2) << lamount;
    cout << "\n Loan Terms (Years): " << year;
    cout << "\n Annual Interest Rate (in decimal): " << fixed << setprecision(2) <<interestr;
    
    total = year * 12;      
    
    cout << "\n Total # Of Payments: " << total;        


    lpayment = (lamount*interestr/12);      
    
    cout << "\n Monthly Payment: $ " << lpayment <<"\n\n";
    
    for (int ctr = 1; ctr <= total; ctr++)
    {
        principal = lamount / total;
        
        ubalance = principal - lamount;
        
        cout <<"\t";
        cout << ctr;
        
        cout <<"\t $ " <<setprecision(2) <<fixed <<lpayment;
        cout <<"\t $ " <<setprecision(2) <<fixed <<principal;
        cout <<"\t $ " <<setprecision(2) <<fixed <<lpayment;
        cout <<"\t $ " <<setprecision(2) <<fixed <<ubalance <<endl;
    }
    
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Post a [mcve] which reproduces youir result. Best as a console program which outputs those values to `cout`(I have no clue how you produced that linked image with that code)

Comment: This is an algorithm problem, not a C++ problem. Could you reproduce the series of calculations on paper? Figure out how to do that, step by step, on paper. Then the code follows naturally. Don't try to create an algorithm in code unless you're very proficient in the language. Work on one hard thing (algorithm or coding) at a time.

Answer (score 0):

I think a while loop is better for this one like so,

```
principal = lamount / total;
while ( ubalance >= 0){
     ubalance = total - lamount;
     cout <<"\t $ " <<setprecision(2) <<fixed <<ubalance <<endl;
}
```

the solution is something like that, and also your question is kinda similar to this question [Trying to make a while Loop that subtracts a number until it reaches desired value and if subtraction surpasses desired value, display it and stop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23312942/trying-to-make-a-while-loop-that-subtracts-a-number-until-it-reaches-desired-val), I may not have provided you the exact answer but at least you got the idea.

Regards,

Joey